# cppunit can't find c++11 libs

Tags: c++, makefile, cross-compiling, yocto, bitbake

I have written a program that I need to compile for `raspberry-pi3` and it must be use `bitbake` for compilation.

All was ok when I wrote `C` code; and i didn't use a dynamic library.

If relevant, I need to use `cppunit`. I already added it in my `rpi-basic-image` and added:

```
    DEPENDS = "cppunit".
```

my make file

```
    CXX = arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
    INCLUDES= -I./
    CXXFLAGS = -g $(INCLUDES)
    SRCM= CBasicMath.cpp
    OBJM = $(SRCM:.cpp=.o)
    LINKFLAGS= -lcppunit
    testbasicmath: TestBasicMath.cpp $(OBJM)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ TestBasicMath.cpp $(OBJM) $(LINKFLAGS) $(LINKFLAGSLOG4) $(LIBLOG)
    # Default compile
    .cpp.o:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    install:
        $(INSTALL) -m 755 testbasicmath ${sbindir}/testbasicmath; 
    clean:
        rm -f *.o *.xml testbasicmath
```

cppunit can't be found c++11 libs

*/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/../lib/libcppunit.so: undefined reference to `std::invalid_argument::invalid_argument(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'*

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -v

Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-12ubuntu1)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: cppunit can't found c++11 libs

Comment: Questions normally end in a squiggly mark `?`. Perhaps more importantly, "cppunit can't found c++11 libs" is not a good description of the problem. A good description contains full unedited text of actual error messages. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is the version of the `g++` compiler? If it is `4.7` then most probably it does not support `C++11` features, also it was enabled in `g++-4.7.2+` or something.

Comment: my  gcc version is 4.7.3

Comment: you probably need to add -std=c++11 to your CXXFLAGS

Comment: it does't help me(

Comment: Yocto already export some variables like CXXFLAGS, so I think your Makefile is not compatible with Yocto. Maybe try to use autotools instead of plain Makefile? You give very little informations about your problem, it is hard to help you.

Comment: 4.7 is too old. You need at least 5.1

Comment: provide the .bb recipe file

Comment: Nayfe you help me so much

Comment: @SkiF you're welcome, i'll copy my comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yocto already export some variables like CXXFLAGS, so you shouldn't override it in your Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

yocto by default exports the CXX flags you just remove the CXX flags defination in Make file.

Comment: i slove my problem just no need to do CXX = arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ bc octo already export some variables like CXX